# Android Multilanguage support

Tags: android, language-agnostic, libgdx, multilingual

I have android application developed in English language and also have content in English. Is this possible that all texts are converted in other language like in Chinese or Japanese, then How? some sample code or tutorial will help me lot.

I am able to get language selected through setting with code as follows.

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage()
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Comment: You might wish to consider editing your question to explain **completely and precisely** how you have implemented "its help screen".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also use translation api. Refer this Link
http://www.creatiosoft.com/how-to-use-microsoft-translation-api-in-android/

Answer (score 5):

The usual way to do this is to:

Enter your strings in a `strings.xml` file in the `/res/values/` folder of your project. You can then define different localizations of your string file by added them to the localized `/res/values/` folders. ( `/res/values-jp/` or `/res/values-en/` etc.)

See: [Developer Android](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html)

Comment: I want to change it dynamically, not manually. There are lots of languages which android devices supports but one can not manually add values like the example above.

Comment: Most if not all languages are supported by the res/values language code extension. For all language codes, see the list of A2 codes: [here](http://userpage.chemie.fu-berlin.de/diverse/doc/ISO_3166.html)

What exactly do you mean by changing the language/strings dynamically?